# как отправить сообщение по нажатию кнопки | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, pycord

Поискав информацию в интернете я нашёл только как создать и отправить саму кнопку. Но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки бот отправлял сообщение
Код кнопки:

```
@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx, *args):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary
    item = discord.ui.Button(style=style, label='test')
    view.add_item(item=item)
    await ctx.send('button test', view=view)
```